# how can exponential of two terms be expressed as sum of the two terms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can exp(x+y) be expressed (or separated) as a sum (and NOT PRODUCTS) of exp(x) and exp(y) only?
exp(x+y)=exp(x)exp(y), is there a way of having this a sum?

Comment: Are you looking for a finite sum (then this will work in special cases only), or is a powerseries acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's not much we can do about the fact that $e^{x + y} = e^x\cdot e^y$.

However, as you note, this is the product of $e^x,\;e^y$, and not a sum of those functions.

What you can do to obtain a sum, though not a sum of $e^x$ and $e^y$, but it is a sum involving $x, y$, is to take the natural log of $e^{x + y}$:

$$\ln\left(e^{x+y}\right) = x + y$$

Comment: Well, you can add another 1 to the sum :-) +1